# Removed DOM elements are still displayed in mobile safari (iOS 5.1)

Tags: javascript, ios, ios5, ios-simulator, mobile-safari

Does anyone has encountered a problem with iOS Safari, when removed elements ( `$("some-selector").html("")`, `$("some-selector").innerHTML` ) are still displayed in mobile safari?
iWebinspector shows only new elements in the DOM tree, outputing container to console also shows that there should be only new content displayed.

Don't know how usefull it is--but it seems that old elements are scrollable, but not clickable. Very strange glitch.

Tested on iPad 2 (not mine, I think it was 5.1), iPhone 4 iOS 5.1, iOS 5.1 iPad simulator.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Removing container itself solved this problem. So I advice You just to remove container and add it again if You encounter same problem.

Comment: I've seen this on iPad when a div containing an iframe is hidden but not deleted caused scrolling/clicking to stop working (the iframe "footprint" stoped events from reaching elements under it.  Deleting the iframe completely solved the issue and scrolling/clicking worked again.  This was specific to iPad as the PlayBook/Android tablets running WebKit had no issues whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks for comment , scunliffe. 
Actually I am using iframe , but it is the element I am adding after deleting old content. The ones that are are removed are div/tables, so  it seems a bit different case.

Comment: any chance you can post a complete sample somewhere (here or on pastebin?)

Comment: scunliffe, there would too many lines of code to paste to understand full example. Actually removing the container itself solved the problem.

So:

1) `$("#content > table, #content > div").remove()` (also - `.first().innerHTML`, `.html('')`) didn't work;
2) `$("content").remove()` worked fine. Just addded it again after removing.

Answer (score 0):

Valid workaround I found was to delete container and add it again (see my last comment so scunliffe for details).